# const qualifier to decltype

Tags: c++, c++11

My first try of using `decltype`

```
vector<int> vals;
const decltype(&vals[0]) ptr;

for (const auto& val : vals)
    ptr = &val;
```

doesn't compile, complaining about assigning to read-only variable `ptr`. What I'm trying to achieve is `ptr` to be of type `const int*`. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: `const int*` and `int* const` are different things, as you may be aware.

Comment: This is why I prefer having `int const*` and `int* const` (const *always* on the right of what it refers to). It is unusual, I know, but for myself, I live quite well with it (does not mean I'm unable to read the other version, too, though...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector` has a `const_pointer` typedef.  You can use that like

```
decltype(vals)::const_pointer ptr;
```

to get the correct const pointer to the vector type ([Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ceb331feac0d19f)).

Comment: Good solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't declare the pointer before you need it. Then you can deduce its type (in this case, the desired `const int*`) in the initialization.

This works:

```
std::vector<int> val {1,2,3,4};

for (const auto &v : val) {
    auto p = &v;
    std::cout << *p;
}
```

This fails:

```
std::vector<int> val {1,2,3,4};

for (const auto &v : val) {
    auto p = &v;
    *p = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `ptr` is basically `const (int *) ptr`, or `int * const ptr`. So the pointer is constant, not the objects it points to.
You can either make `vals` `const`, or at least cast it to `const` inside the `decltype`, or use `std::vector`'s typedefs instead of `decltype`.

Comment: Note that C++17's `std::as_const` can help easily cast an object to const

Comment: Wouldn't `as_const` (and `add_const`) also affect the outer type, not the type pointed to?

Comment: `std::vector::operator[]` returns a `const_reference` if the vector is itself `const` (and a simple `reference` otherwise). So the address of the `const_reference` would be a `const int*`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, you're using `as_const` on the vector before accessing a single element.  Nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is not textual substitution.  `decltype` is not textual substitution.  The modifier `const` applies to the entire thing it's applied to, it doesn't reach inside the result of decltype to change the left-most thing.

This would work though, because now `const` is applied to the element type to make the type `(const int)`, and then `ptr` is made a pointer to that:

```
const std::remove_reference<decltype(vals[0])>::type * ptr;
```

Note that this one wouldn't work, since it uselessly tries to `const`-qualify a reference type:

```
std::add_pointer<const decltype(vals[0])>::type ptr;
```

Comment: `decltype(vals[0])` is `int &`.

Comment: @T.C.: Hmm, and the type system isn't smart enough to collapse that when you try to form a pointer to it?  Blah.